# mod_rewrite check public folder before passing to php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

What I am trying to achieve (with mod_rewrite) is on request check if a file/directory exists in the public folder, if it does, serve it, if not, route the request to the index.php file. Also if no extension provided in the URL then default to .html.

Below is my folder structure:

```
/.htaccess
/index.php
/public
    /test.html
    /test.xml
    /a_folder
        /index.html
        /test.html
```

So for example here are a few requests and responses:

- **example.com/test.xml** >>> **/public/test.xml**
- **example.com/a_folder/** >>> **/public/a_folder/index.html**
- **example.com/a_folder/test** >>> **/public/a_folder/test.html**
- **example.com/not_in_public** >>> **/index.php**

Any pointers on this would be amazing, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jxpx777 and @N1xx1 after a bit of juggling made it work.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ - [L]

# Check public cache
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1/index

# Add .html if not extension provided
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

# Push through stack in not in cache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: (Heavily cribbed from my WordPress .htaccess file)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)^(\.\w+) $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `$1.html` line is off the top of my head and may need some tweaking. Note that this is a dumb check that the requested URL ends in a dot followed by one or more word characters.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this, wasn't exactly what I was after but it has helped me find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(|index\.php)$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [R]
</IfModule>
```

This should do the trick.

Basically, if it's `/` or `/index.php` it won't do anything, if it's `/public/whateveryouwant` it won't do anything, if it's anything else it will rewrite to `/public/whateveryouwant` and check if it's either a file or a directory. If it's not it will redirect to `index.php`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this, wasn't exactly what I was after but it has helped me find the answer.